# Problema con los session start al subir la pagina a un hosting

Tags: php, session, hosting

Quisiera saber porque al subir la pagina a un hosting gratuito me lanza este error siempre y como solucionarlo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el código donde marca el error.

Comment: El servidor de hosting está mal configurado, el disco está lleno o tu usuario no tiene suficiente _quota_ disponible para escribir más en el disco.. ¿Si tienes acceso a esa carpeta temp? ¿puedes crear archivos en ella? ¿has intentado con otro hosting?

Comment: Pues @jachguate no he mirado esa parte quizas sea eso lo revisaré

Comment: Juan Daniel ya postee una foto del código donde dice que esta el error

Comment: stiwar: utiliza la notación [arroba]usuario, de otra manera @JuanDaniel no recibe notificación de tu respuesta. Por otro lado, no publiques imágenes con código, publica directamente el código como texto en tu pregunta. Un saludo.